# Can not get text centered same time when outer box is the middle

Tags: html, css

I am developing a mobile UI and have problem with css. I have a swiper menu for mobile UI and when user swipes there should be a box in the middle of swipe area and there should be a text in the middle of the box, however I can not do both of these, if I do one I lose the other one.

I tried both css class in same divs, then created 2 divs but not work as intended. Text in the box goes in the middle as expected but box allings to left.

Second one has 2 inner divs with 2 css class, same as without not `tabCenter` class. Box in the middle but Text allign in top left.

```css
.tabCenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.call-button-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 233px;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #29A3D8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: lato-bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-button-container tabCenter" @click="makeCall(true)">Video {{activeCall.to}}
</div>

<div class="call-button-container" @click="startCall(false)">
  <div Class="tabCenter">Call {{activeCall.to}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can solve your problem...

```
.call-button-container.tabCenter {
    display: table-cell;
}

.call-button-container {
    display: table;
}
```

Or you can use .call-button-container:first-child as selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .call-button-container{
           display:flex;
           justify-content:center;
           align-items:center;
         }
```

this css will solve the problem